# Implement a "static observer pattern"

Tags: c++, observer-pattern

I have a class with a method template:

```
struct Subject
{
  template <typename T>
  void doSomething()
  {
    ..
  }
};
```

Now whenever `doSomething` is called (with any `T`) I would like to have an "Observer" be notified:

```
  template <typename T>
  void onDoSomething()
  {
    ..
  }
```

It's important that the observer is a method template (class template with contained method would work as well). If it wasn't, I could just implement the common observer pattern.

It would be ok to modify `Subject::doSomething()`so that it calls a method. However, the class `Subject` should not "know" the concrete Observer / observer method.

The idea behind this is: I use `Subject` in two projects. I need (and have) the observer only in one of them.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can't use C++11 features. But even if I could, I don't see how this solves my specific question?

Comment: @Philipp you are right, it doesn't help. I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 2):

Tough one. It seems to boil down to

> Notification must be resolvable at compile time (it's a template)

and, at the same time,

> The notification should not be resolvable at compile time (`Subject` shouldn't know the observer)

I can think of two ways to do it:

---

`1.` Add an overload of `doSomething`:

```
template <typename T, typename Observer>
void doSomething()
{
  doSomething<T>();
  Observer::onDoSomething<T>();
}
```

Then call the one-parameter version in project A, and the two-parameter version in project B.

---

`2.` Have the file defining `Subject` include a header which will be different/differently-configured in each project:

**Subject.h**

```
#include "observer_def.hpp"

struct Subject
{
  template <typename T>
  void doSomething()
  {
    ..
    notifyDoSomething<T>();
  }
};
```

**observer_def.hpp in project A**:

```
template <typename>
inline void notifyDoSomething() {}
```

**observer_def.hpp in project B**:

```
template <typename T>
inline void notifyDoSomething()
{
  MyObserver::onDoSomething<T>();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your ideas. Method 1 is not desirable because `doSomething` is called deeply within some other methods which I don't want to change. Method 2 didn't look like modern C++ style to me. I guess the solution I found (see other answer) is more what I needed, but +1 anyways.

Comment: @Philipp: actually, your solution requires exactly the same preprocessor machinery that `Angew` used... though I would recommend using a `#ifdef ... #else ... #endif` block rather than two different files (it's less confusing).

Comment: @MatthieuM. That's why I said "different/differently-configured." I was trying to cover the `#ifdef` option as well.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a satisfying solution by means of template specialization:

```
///signaling struct. Could be replaced with any other type.
struct SpecializedObserver{};

///unspecialized:
template <typename>
struct Observer
{
    template <typename T>
    static void onDoSomething()
    {
        //default: do nothing.
    }
};

///optional. Specialize in project A or leave aside in project B:
template<>
struct Observer<SpecializedObserver>
{
    template <typename T>
    static void onDoSomething()
    {
        std::cout << "doing something with " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl; 
    }
};

struct Subject
{
    template <typename T>
    void doSomething()
    {
      Observer<SpecializedObserver>::onDoSomething<T>();
      ..
    }
};
```

This solution doesn't require any action if I don't want an Observer. In case I want to have one, I specialize the Observer template as shown above.

**EDIT:** This worked fine in my test, however the question is how I can use this in a scenario with different compilation units - where should I define the specialization?

Comment: The specialization should be visible at the point of use. It therefore should be included before `Subject::doSomething` is defined... which requires preprocessor hackery (`#ifdef...`) and therefore one wonders why use a template specialization and not just a different definition of a non-template `Observer` class.